# "One or more error occurred" When right clicking form elements

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

When working with either a Custom or Standard Form in AX 7, right-clicking on the Design Node, Grid Container, Group Control etc. Visual Studio freezes for a couple of seconds then displays this error message: "One or more error occurred".

This is not isolated on my development VM, coworkers also experiencing the same issue.

Anyone ran into this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember running into this and you can follow these steps to clear the cache.

1. Delete the contents from the following folders

   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
2. Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command “devenv /resetuserdata” from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

   - Typical location for 64 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
   - Typical location for 32 bit: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Per:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/